# Phonegap to Phonegap communication

Tags: cordova, wifi, communication

I'm starting with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile, and I want to communicate between different Phonegap devices with a wifi connection. What is the best way to achieve this? I need a suggestion on what technology is better for this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use BlueTooth thru the plugin present in https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Bluetooth or u have to establish connection via a centralized webserver u are familiar with

Answer (score 0):

With Phonegap you need use Bluethooth how @sunil_reddy says or use a server of intermediary in the comunication. Using a server or web service you can create a chat, send files, etc...

First you conect you send the content to the server and the server establish the connection with the other device.

The more easy mode its a bluethooth plugin but depend where you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a SignalR server.

e.g. Phone A send a message to Phone B

- Phone A CALL SignalR server send method, then
- SignalR server CALL Phone B receive method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess all the answers above are logically correct. I simple terms - when you try to communicate from one device to another, either you open a communication channel across them (Bluetooth allows you to create a server and a corresponding client socket) or use a server in between to relay the communication. Depending on what exactly you wish to achieve, you need to decide which mode to go for.
Since you mentioned about WiFi - I assume you are looking at P2P connection over WiFi. So, this may/should be of interest to you:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html